# How to force a Mac to restart without pressing the power key?

Tags: ssh, reboot

The Finder was not responding, so I control+click'd the Finder icon on the Dock and chose Relaunch… except that it didn't relaunch.

Activity Monitor happened to be visible and I could see that it listed Finder (including the PID) and showed it as "Not Responding."

I was in iTerm, so I tried `killall Finder` and was told "No processes belonging to you were found" (or words to that effect).

I tried to send "kill" to the PID I could see for Finder, and was told there was no such PID. This led me to assume that the WindowServer was not showing accurate information anymore.

I tried `sudo killall -HUP WindowServer` which made the entire GUI go away, and left me with a black screen and some white letters on it (*not* the panic screen, more like console log messages).

The message was:

> Sep 27 17:17:23 Pro kernel[0]: V1.4.0: TrustedData_driver_VendorSpecificType00::vendorSpecificPassThroughIn(): SendCommand failed, task not complete, serviceResponse = 1, TaskStatus: 2
>
> Sep 27 17:17:23 Pro kernel[0]: V1.4.0: TrustedData_UserClient_SCSIType00::vendorSpecificPassThroughIn() returning failure from driver: 3758097084

So now I have a black screen, but and I can type but it has no effect (the letters appear on the screen, but don't actually execute. I've tried control-C and control-Z to no avail.

I *can* ssh into it from my other Mac.

Of course my first step was `sudo shutdown -r now` which sent out the notice that the system was going to shutdown, but didn't.

I have also tried `sudo shutdown -ro now` and `sudo /sbin/reboot` and `sudo reboot -q` to no avail.

> *Aside: (On a Windows PC, I would have pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd> but there is no corresponding Mac keyboard shortcut… not that it would have necessarily worked anyway.)*

### I am out of ideas.

I ran `ps` and [put the output here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18414/ase/cant-reboot-ps.txt) if anyone wants to see what *is* still running.

### What else would *you* try?

**(Other than simply holding down the power button until it shuts off.)**

Comment: I've had this issue, too. The only solution I've known to work is to hold down the power button.

Comment: *Coda:* the kernel.log showed that there was an issue with an external drive. I ended up using `mount' to find the disk info, and then `diskutil eject /dev/{disk}` (using the /Volumes/{mountName} did mot work, I needed the 'disk#s'). Once the drive was 'ejected' I physically disconnected the drive, and then `shutdown` worked as expected. FWIW in case others run into a similar situation.

Comment: So in the end the question you wanted answered was really "why won't my Mac shut down" rather than "How to force a Mac to restart without pressing the power key?"

Comment: No, not at all, the question still stands, because you can get into that situation (won't shutdown) by a variety of routes. I just wanted to share what my experience was in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `ssh` onto your Mac
- Type `sudo su -l` to switch to superuser mode
- Enter your admin password
- type `halt` and hit enter

This sends SIGTERM (and subsequently SIGKILL) to all running processes and powers the system off.

**Note:** Type `man halt` for other options.

**EDIT:** You could also try `launchctl shutdown`

Comment: Interestingly, I can run `man halt` as an admin user (but not root), but it shows the manual for reboot(8).

Comment: Yeah when I added that note about not being able to view the manual entry for halt unless your superuser I had confused myself because I had been trying a couple of things at once.  I've removed it now.

Comment: `halt` is a synonym for `reboot` on Darwin/BSD. You can also use `sudo shutdown now` - There's also no need to go to `su` superuser mode as a separate stage. Just `sudo reboot` will be enough, then enter the password when prompted.

Comment: Sudo reboot didn't work for him as he already said

Comment: I'll definitely try 'launchctl shutdown' next time. That was one way I hadn't heard of before.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer. It has a good list of options, especially the launchctl one which I bet a lot of people don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut for initiating a shutdown while bypassing the "are you sure" dialog is:

```
control + option + command + eject
```

And the keyboard shortcut for initiating a reboot while bypassing the "are you sure" dialog is:

```
control + command + eject
```

I'm not 100% sure if these are dependent on Finder being responsive.

Answer (score 0):

One tip, if you use sudo su, always use sudo su - , this will ensure root's environment gets setup properly.

Chances are launchd got all sorts of messed up and for the most part, I've never found a way to recover from that short of simply powering off the machine hard.  Launchd is more or less the OS X version of init under Linux.  It technically isn't the first process, but it might as well be.  If it goes, then the system simply isn't going to be able to shutdown properly.

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I amended the `su` command as I had omitted the `-l` which is the same as your suggested `-`.  If it was intended as a comment on my solution it should really have been a comment rather than an answer though.  Thanks

Comment: FWIW `ps auxwww| sort -k 2|head -1` shows that launch is the first process, at least when I'm logged in. I thought that the -o in `sudo shutdown -r -o now` was supposed to 'bypass' launchd but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yea I wish I could move it :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just found a non-obvious answer. In my case, running `sudo shutdown -r` would cause the message to be printed, but no shutdown would happen as the OP said. Turns out, running `shutdown -r` *without* sudo caused the restart to happen. Hope this helps!